# No Manifest Detected Flutter PWA

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web, manifest.json

Although there is a valid `manifest.json` and `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` in the head tag, chrome shows **No Manifest Detected**, service workers are installed successfully and `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manifest.json` is fine and accessible, but chrome not even requesting the `manifest.json` file! this is a flutter project which currently build for web using `flutter build web --release`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the bug was introduced by `flutter_native_splash` which added some `picture` tag to the root of html page which caused the chrome not requesting the `manifest.json`, so moving the picture tag to body solved the issue.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Comment: https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/202